# How to remove all sub paths?

Tags: c++

I am a new in C++ (and I think there is should be much shorter way to do what I need), but what I need to do is:

I have a `vector` of paths to folders

```
C:\\Sessions\\MyFolder 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_03 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02\\test 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\777\\folder
```

I need to remove all paths that are sub path of final path. It is means that finally I need to get such result

```
C:\\Sessions\\MyFolder 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_03 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02\\test 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\777\\folder
```

These paths were removed

```
C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02 
C:\\Sessions\\Calib
```

Because this path `C:\\Sessions\\Calib` subpath of `C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02` and actually this path `C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02` is subpath of `C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02\\test`.

This path `C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02\\test` doesn't have subpath in given list of paths, so we leave it.

I wrote such method

```
/*static*/ std::vector<std::string> Utils::remove_sub_folders(std::vector<std::string> folderPaths_in)
    {
        std::vector<std::string> result;
        std::vector<std::string> executed_paths;
        std::vector<std::string> folder_paths = folderPaths_in;
        std::sort(folder_paths.begin(), folder_paths.end());

        for each (auto & path in folder_paths)
        {
            std::vector<std::string> path_split = Utils::split(path, "\\");

            for each (auto & compare_path in folder_paths)
            {
                bool is_have_alredy_processed = false;

                for each (auto & processed_path in executed_paths)
                {
                    if (compare_path == processed_path)
                    {
                        is_have_alredy_processed = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (!is_have_alredy_processed)
                {
                    std::vector<std::string> compare_path_split = Utils::split(compare_path, "\\");

                    int path_split_size = static_cast<int>(path_split.size());
                    int path_compare_size = static_cast<int>(compare_path_split.size());

                    if (path != compare_path && path_compare_size >= path_split_size)
                    {
                        int min_size = min(path_split_size, path_compare_size);

                        bool is_equal_begin = true;

                        for (int i = 0; i < min_size; i++)
                        {
                            std::string path_word = path_split[i];
                            std::string compare_word = compare_path_split[i];

                            if (path_word != compare_word)
                            {
                                is_equal_begin = false;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if ((!is_equal_begin && path_split_size == path_compare_size))
                        {
                            result.push_back(path);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            executed_paths.push_back(path);
        }

        return result;
    }
```

I can't understand what I am missing, but actuall result I get is :

```
C:\Sessions\Calib
C:\Sessions\Calib\2020_04_30_18_02
C:\Sessions\Calib\2020_04_30_18_02\test
```

This is how I call this method:

```
std::vector<std::string> all_dirs_by_path{
            "C:\\Sessions\\MyFolder",
            "C:\\Sessions\\Calib",
            "C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02",
            "C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_03",
            "C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\2020_04_30_18_02\\test",
            "C:\\Sessions\\Calib\\777\\folder",
        };
std::vector<std::string> final_dirs_by_path = Utils::remove_sub_folders(all_dirs_by_path);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You start by sorting the given paths. However, the order in which it sorts is propably not what you expect. The reason is that sorting `std::string`s does not treat the directory separator `\` in any special way. And `\` sorts later than upper case characters, but earlier than lower case characters. What you would want is a comparison function that is a bit smarter about paths, and sorts them by looking at each path component separately.

If you can use [C++17's filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) (or the [Boost filesystem library](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.filesystem)), then you should create a vector of [`std::filesystem::path`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/path)s. These have an `operator<()` that compares paths in the way you expect them to. Once you sort those, then you have the nice property that any parent path will come before a child path, and there are no paths between a parent and child path that don't have the same parent:

```
C:\Foo
C:\Foo\Bar
C:\Foo\Baz
C:\Quux
...
```

So then it's quite easy, traverse the list, and at any path in the list, check if the *next* path in the list is a child of the current path. If so, you can discard the current path.

```
using namespace fs = std::filesystem; // or use boost::filesystem here

static bool is_parent(const fs::path &parent, const fs::path &child) {
    auto parent_size = std::distance(parent.begin(), parent.end());
    auto child_size = std::distance(child.begin(), child.end());
    return child_size > parent_size && std::equal(parent.begin(), parent.end(), child.begin());
}

std::vector<fs::path> remove_sub_folders(std::vector<fs::path> paths) {
   std::sort(paths.begin(), paths.end());
   std::vector<fs::path> result;

   for(auto cur = paths.begin(); cur != paths.end(); ++cur) {
       auto next = std::next(cur);
       if (next == paths.end() || !is_parent(*cur, *next))
           result.push_back(*cur);
   }

   return result;
}
```

If you want to do it with `std::string`, then you have to write a custom comparison function that does what `std::filesystem::path::operator<()` does, and pass that to `std::sort()`. To check if one is a parent of the other, ensure you have a trailing directory separator in the parent path, then just check if the child path starts with the parent path.

Comment: You save my day!)) Thanks!